# Update part of a URL in page using only Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript

I need to update the date (in YYYY-MM-DD format) in a link using only Javascript.  The page has 100's of links but it's always to the same core URL.  The querystring variable names are always the same as well but some of the variable values change.  The dates however are all the same - they need to be tomorrow's date so when the page is called the date will always be the next day.

I could move the date to be at the start or end of the URL querystring but I'd prefer not to.

I know document.write is not an elegant way to do this so hence asking here for suggestions.

Server side technologies are unfortunately not an option hence the need for Javascript.

website.com/buy-ticket?from=Manchester&to=London&dateDepart=2014-08-07&dateArrive=2014-08-07
website.com/buy-ticket?from=Liverpool&to=York&dateDepart=2014-08-07&dateArrive=2014-08-07

We have JQuery installed if that makes it easier.

Comment: Without serverside processing, can't you use a texteditor's S&R?

Comment: since you are willing to use jQuery, you could get a list of all links `$("a")` in your page, run a `.each()` on them and get their `href` attribute, then find the query string using `indexof('?')`, run a `.replace()` on the query string using a regex for your dates and replace all of them, then reconstruct the link and stick it back into the `href`, all in the `.each()` loop.

Comment: I can use texteditor S&R but that means that I've got to update the page daily.  I'm basically looking for a Javascript replacement for writing out tomorrow's date using Server Side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you should do this server-side as it doesn't rely on your site's visitor having JavaScript enabled. However, as you have stated this is not an option, you can still do this with JavaScript. There are many ways to accomplish this, below is how I would tackle it:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var parseQueryString = function parseQueryString(qs) {
            var params = qs.split('&'), // split up into individual parameter/value pairs
                kvp = []; // declare an array
            params.forEach(function (pairing, index, array) {
                var pair = pairing.split('='), // split up into key/value
                    key = pair[0], // key will always be on left side
                    value = pair[1] || ''; // value, if defined, will be on right, otherwise default to an empty string
                kvp.push({ // add to the array as an object
                    "key": key,
                    "value": value
                });
            });
            return kvp; // return the array
        },
        swapParameters = function swapParameters(kvp, params) {
            var key;
            for (key in params) { // loop through the parameters
                if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    kvp.forEach(function (pair, index, array) { // loop through the key-value pairs
                        if (key === pair.key) { // if one of them matches the current parameter
                            pair.value = params[key]; // update the value of the pair to the new parameter value
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
            return kvp; // return the modified key-value pairs
        },
        stringifyKVP = function stringifyKVP(kvp) {
            var s = []; // declare an array
            kvp.forEach(function (pair, index, array) { // loop through the key-value pairs
                s.push('' + pair.key + '=' + pair.value); // create a string of key=value and push to the array
            });
            return s.join('&'); // use join to return the stringified key-value pairs separated with an &
        },
        padLeft = function padLeft(value, places) { // quick & dirty pad function
            var padding = Array(places - value.toString().length + 1).join('0'),
                padded = padding + value;
            return padded;
        },
        getFormattedDate = function getFormattedDate(date) { // quick & dirty format date function
            var yyyy = date.getFullYear().toString(),
                mm = padLeft(date.getMonth() + 1, 2),
                dd = padLeft(date.getDate(), 2);
            return yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
        },
        testUrl1 = 'website.com/buy-ticket?from=Manchester&to=London&dateDepart=2014-08-07&dateArrive=2014-08-07',
        testUrl2 = 'website.com/buy-ticket?from=Liverpool&to=York&dateDepart=2014-08-07&dateArrive=2014-08-07',
        today = getFormattedDate(new Date()), // get the current date formatted as YYYY-MM-DD
        test = function test(url) { // tie it all together
            var parts = url.split('?'), // split the querystring from the url
                resource = parts[0], // host & path are always left side
                qs = parts[1], // qs is always right side, assumes qs always exists
                kvp = parseQueryString(qs), // break the qs up into key-value pairs
                newParams = swapParameters(kvp, { // swap out new values
                    "dateDepart": today,
                    "dateArrive": today
                });
            qs = stringifyKVP(newParams); // get the new querystring
            return resource + '?' + qs; // return the modified resource
        };
    console.log(test(testUrl1)); // log to console for proof of "working"
    console.log(test(testUrl2));
}());
```

You can run this in your browser console.

As far as jQuery goes, jQuery will make selecting the `a` elements to process much simpler. A selector like this should do the trick nicely:

```
$('a[href^="website.com/buy-ticket?"]')
```

That will select all `a` elements that have an `href` attribute starting with `website.com/buy-ticket?`. The question mark at the end should ensure that the querystring exists. You may have to modify that to include the protocol:

```
$('a[href^="http://website.com/buy-ticket?"]')
```

You could also simply use the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$('a[href*="website.com/buy-ticket?"]')
```

### Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jqk27/

Comment: Perfect thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Example is clear and well commented so I've got my head around how it works. 
Sorry I can't up vote your answer as I haven't got enough reputation yet.  I'll make sure I do when I have!

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
  <script>
    var param1var = getQueryVariable("dateDepart");

    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
          return pair[1];
        }
      } 
      console.log ('Query Variable ' + variable + ' was not found !');
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: what does this have to do with changing href in links?